# oledb connect to SQL 2012 on windows 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, oledb

I've install IIS on Server2016 and run asp classic for connect sql 2012 at another server.

1) I cannot use "Provider=SQLOLEDB". 
2) i install ole db native client for 2012
   and use "Provider=SQLNCLI11", it work 
   But when call query "SELECT SYSDATETIME() "

it return "6/19/2018 2:08:01 PM"

should be "2018-06-19 14:08:40.8574320"

Please help!

Comment: It seems you are using ADO classic. ADO classic has not been enhanced for many years and is unaware of SQL Server data types introduced after SQL Server 2000, such as `datetime2`, even if you use a newer OLE DB provider. I think you'll need to format the value in T-SQL as the desired string to return the value because ASP classic doesn't have a suitable datetime structure for the value. This is the sort of pain you incur using old technologies. ADO.NET and ASP.NET support datetime2 natively.

Comment: Note that `SELECT GETDATE()` will give you the result as a `DATETIME`, which ADO does support. If that was just an example and columns are actually using `DATETIME2` values, that doesn't help, but you could convert those to `DATETIME` before processing.

Comment: Thank Jeroen ,  I still run success on IIS server 2008 connect to SQL 2012.